# Android - приложение для смс по умолчанию

Tags: java, android

Android 11 / api 30,
Как можно назначить/запросить разрешение для того чтобы сделать приложение основным для смс?

Comment: Доступ к чтению смс в манифесте, и система сама спросит

Answer (score 1):

Надо сделать так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, myPackageName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Где `myPackageName` имя пакета вашего приложения для обработки SMS

При этом предполагается, что ваше приложение должно уметь минимум 4 вещи:

1. Перехватывать (уметь обрабатывать) бродкаст при получении SMS: `action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"`
2. Перехватывать (уметь обрабатывать) бродкаст при получении MMS: `action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER"`
3. Иметь `Intent` обрабатывающий создание новых сообщений: `action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND/SENDTO`"
4. Иметь сервис для "быстрого" ответа, типа:

```
    <service
            android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Только при выполнении этих условий вы увидите при запуске `Intent`'а диалог подтверждения смены приложения для обработки SMS

Comment: Версия Android и API level какие?